# My order form keeps sending me to the error page when I test it

Tags: php

This should be simple, but I've been playing with it for two days and get it to work. When I reached the Thank you page, there was no data in the email. Now, I can't get past the error page.

**HTML form:**

```
 <form action="send_group_photo_order.php" method="post" name="GroupPhoto" id="GroupPhoto" title="GroupPhoto">
      <p>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" form="GroupPhoto" title="name" size="50" />
      </p>
      <p>Student ID #:
        <input name="id" type="text" id="id" form="GroupPhoto" title="id" />
  </p>
      <p>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" id="email" form="GroupPhoto" title="email" size="50" />
      </p>
      <p>Phone
        <label for="phone">:</label>
        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" form="GroupPhoto" title="phone" />
        <br />
        <br />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="orders[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" form="GroupPhoto" title="GroupCD" value="cd" />
        <label for="type1">I want Digital Photos on a CD for $5.00 </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="orders[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" form="GroupPhoto" title="Group-Print-Package" value="prints" />
        <label for="type2">I want the Full Color Print Package for $25.00<br />
          <br />
        </label>
      </p>
      <input name="orders[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" form="GroupPhoto" title="Acknowledge" value="acknowledge"/>
        <label for="type3">I understand that I must pay for this service in full before the photos will be printed. I will  
    receive a preview copy via email prior to printing. This will be a locked file.<br />
          <br />
        </label>
    <input name='submit' type="submit" form="GroupPhoto" value="submit" id="submit" />
    </form>
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "yearbook@gphs-go4news.com";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "order_photos.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank-you.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
$id = $_REQUEST['id'] ;
$selectedOrders  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['orders']) && is_array($_POST['orders']) && count($_POST['orders']) > 0){
    $selectedProjects = implode(', ', $_POST['orders']);
}

$body .= 'Selected orders: ' . $selectedOrders;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
$injections = array('(\n+)',
'(\r+)',
'(\t+)',
'(%0A+)',
'(%0D+)',
'(%08+)',
'(%09+)'
);
$inject = join('|', $injections);
$inject = "/$inject/i";
if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($email_address) || empty($comments)) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Feedback Form Results",
$comments, "From: $email" );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

Comment: What does the "error page" say?

Comment: Basic debugging is in order here. If your script is always redirecting to `$error_page`, you must comment out the `header()` calls one at a time to determine which one is at fault (it may be more than one) and instead of performing a redirection, inspect the affected variables like `var_dump($email_address);` and `var_dump($comments);` to find out which validation fails.

Comment: As an aside, _always_ call `exit();` immediately after a `header("Location...")`. If you have additional code that can be reached (not in a different `if/else` condition for example) PHP may still execute it even though you intend to end the script by redirection.  This is a frequent source of really hard to find bugs (though it isn't your problem here)

Comment: Last point: Always when developing code, make sure you have `display_errors` enabled. At the top of your script, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` so any PHP warnings and notices are printed to the screen. Any empty values in `$_REQUEST` are going to issue `Notice undefined index...` the way you have it coded right now since you don't have `isset()` calls on `$email = $_REQUEST['email'];` and the others.

Comment: When I added your great code the message returned:Notice: Undefined variable: body in /hermes/bosoraweb149/b1648/glo.gphsgo4newscom/yearbook/send_group_photo_order.php on line 30 Warning: mail() expects at most 5 parameters, 8 given in /hermes/bosoraweb149/b1648/glo.gphsgo4newscom/yearbook/send_group_photo_order.php on line 73 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosoraweb149/b1648/glo.gphsgo4newscom/yearbook/send_group_photo_order.php:30) in /hermes/bosoraweb149/b1648/glo.gphsgo4newscom/yearbook/send_group_photo_order.php on line 74

Comment: I deleted line 30 and that error stopped; mail() expects at most 5 parameters, 8 given in  on line 71...THIS IS LINE 71...   $email,$name,$phone,$id,$selectedOrders, "From: $email" );  Selected orders is a group of 3 check boxes in an array. The other problem has something to do with headers - I don't understand...Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at 71) in php on line 72 LINE 72...header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );